# Why am I getting the "font has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync" error, when all I did was restart the server?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, fonts, font-family

So I was working on my project and it was all going great until I restarted the server (I'm using expo). When I reloaded, I'm getting the error that the font has not been loaded thru Font.Loadasync. I didn't change any code related to the font. Here is my App.js, and WelcomeScreen.js, respectively:

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import { NavigationContainer, DefaultTheme } from "@react-navigation/native";
import * as Font from 'expo-font';

import Welcome from "./screens/WelcomeScreen"
import CreateAccount from "./screens/CreateAccount";
import LoginScreen from "./screens/LoginScreen";
import Intro1 from "./screens/Intro1";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const loadFonts = async () => {
  await Font.loadAsync({
    'axiforma-black': require('./fonts/Axiforma-Black.ttf'),
    'axiforma-black-italic': require('./fonts/Axiforma-BlackItalic.ttf'),
    'axiforma-bold': require('./fonts/Axiforma-Bold.ttf'),
    'axiforma-bold-italic': require('./fonts/Axiforma-BoldItalic.ttf'),
    'axiforma-book': require('./fonts/Axiforma-Book.ttf'),
    'axiforma-book-italic': require('./fonts/Axiforma-BookItalic.ttf'),
    'axiforma-extra-bold': require('./fonts/Axiforma-Bold.ttf'),
    'axiforma-extra-bold-italic': require('./fonts/Axiforma-BoldItalic.ttf'),
    'axiforma-heavy': require('./fonts/Axiforma-Heavy.ttf'),
    'axiforma-heavy-italic': require('./fonts/Axiforma-HeavyItalic.ttf'),
    'axiforma-italic': require('./fonts/Axiforma-Italic.ttf'),
    'axiforma-light': require('./fonts/Axiforma-Light.ttf'),
    'axiforma-light-italic': require('./fonts/Axiforma-LightItalic.ttf'),
    'axiforma-medium': require('./fonts/Axiforma-Medium.ttf'),
    'axiforma-medium-italic': require('./fonts/Axiforma-MediumItalic.ttf'),
    'axiforma-regular': require('./fonts/Axiforma-Regular.ttf'),
    'axiforma-semibold': require('./fonts/Axiforma-SemiBold.ttf'),
    'axiforma-semibold-italic': require('./fonts/Axiforma-SemiBoldItalic.ttf'),
    'axiforma-thin': require('./fonts/Axiforma-Thin.ttf'),
    'axiforma-thin-italic': require('./fonts/Axiforma-ThinItalic.ttf'),
  });
};

function App() {
  
  const [fontsLoaded, setFontsLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadFonts().then(() => setFontsLoaded(true));
  }, []);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component={Welcome} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Create Account" component={CreateAccount} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Intro 1" component={Intro1} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, StatusBar, ImageBackground, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';

const WelcomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    'axiforma-black': require('../fonts/Axiforma-Black.ttf'),
    'axiforma-black-italic': require('../fonts/Axiforma-BlackItalic.ttf'),
    'axiforma-bold': require('../fonts/Axiforma-Bold.ttf'),
    'axiforma-bold-italic': require('../fonts/Axiforma-BoldItalic.ttf'),
    'axiforma-book': require('../fonts/Axiforma-Book.ttf'),
    'axiforma-book-italic': require('../fonts/Axiforma-BookItalic.ttf'),
    'axiforma-extra-bold': require('../fonts/Axiforma-ExtraBold.ttf'),
    'axiforma-extra-bold-italic': require('../fonts/Axiforma-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf'),
    'axiforma-heavy': require('../fonts/Axiforma-Heavy.ttf'),
    'axiforma-heavy-italic': require('../fonts/Axiforma-HeavyItalic.ttf'),
    'axiforma-italic': require('../fonts/Axiforma-Italic.ttf'),
    'axiforma-light': require('../fonts/Axiforma-Light.ttf'),
    'axiforma-light-italic': require('../fonts/Axiforma-LightItalic.ttf'),
    'axiforma-medium': require('../fonts/Axiforma-Medium.ttf'),
    'axiforma-medium-italic': require('../fonts/Axiforma-MediumItalic.ttf'),
    'axiforma-regular': require('../fonts/Axiforma-Regular.ttf'),
    'axiforma-semibold': require('../fonts/Axiforma-SemiBold.ttf'),
    'axiforma-semibold-italic': require('../fonts/Axiforma-SemiBoldItalic.ttf'),
    'axiforma-thin': require('../fonts/Axiforma-Thin.ttf'),
    'axiforma-thin-italic': require('../fonts/Axiforma-ThinItalic.ttf'),
  });

  return (
    <View style={styles.mainView}>
      <StatusBar translucent backgroundColor='transparent' />
      <ImageBackground source={require("../images/verticalGradient.png")} resizeMode="cover" style={styles.image}>
        <Image source={require("../images/QuirkLogoWhite.png")} style={ styles.logo }/>
        <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', marginLeft: -50, marginTop: 100}}>
          <Text style={styles.heading1}>Welcome</Text>
          <Text style={styles.heading2}>to your Social</Text>
          <View style={{height: 45}}>
            <Text style={styles.heading3}>Playground!</Text>
            <Image source={require("../images/underline.png")} style={styles.underline} resizeMode='contain'/>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={{marginTop: 150}}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.Touchable1} activeOpacity={0.7} onPress={() => {navigation.navigate("Intro 1")}}>
            <Text style={styles.touchableText1}>Get started</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.Touchable2} activeOpacity={0.7}>
            <Text style={styles.touchableText2}>I'll do it later</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <View style={{ width: 300, marginTop: -10, marginBottom: -40 }}>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
              <Text style={{color: '#666'}}>By signing up, you agree to our</Text>
              <Text style={{color: '#0070E0'}}> Terms</Text>
              <Text style={{color: '#666'}}> and </Text>
            </View>
          <Text style={{color: '#0070E0'}}>Privacy Policy</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 80, marginBottom: -70}}>
          <Text style={{color: '#666', fontSize: 16, fontFamily: 'axiforma-regular'}}>Already have an account?</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.6} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Login")}>
            <Text style={{color: '#0070E0', fontSize: 16, fontFamily: 'axiforma-regular'}}> Log in</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  )
}

export default WelcomeScreen

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  underline: {
    width: 250,
    position: 'absolute',
    marginLeft: -35,
    marginTop: -50,
    tintColor: '#0070E0'
  },
  logo: {
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    marginTop: -100,
    marginBottom: 30
  },
  mainView: {
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    flex: 1,
  },
  image: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  heading1: {
    color: 'white',
    fontFamily: 'axiforma-bold',
    fontSize: 34
  },
  heading2: {
    color: 'white',
    fontFamily: 'axiforma-bold',
    fontSize: 34,
    marginTop: -7
  },
  heading3: {
    color: 'white',
    fontFamily: 'axiforma-bold',
    fontSize: 35,
    marginTop: -7,
  },
  Touchable1: {
    height: 40,
    width: 300,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginVertical: 5,
    marginBottom: -5
  },
  Touchable2: {
    height: 40,
    width: 300,
    borderRadius: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: 'white',
    marginVertical: 20
  },
  touchableText1: {
    color: 'black',
    fontSize: 17,
    fontWeight: '700'
  },
  touchableText2: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 17,
    fontWeight: '600'
  },
})
```

I rewrote the entire font related code, but the error still persists, what should I do?